# Submitting HTML form to database using PHP and it brings back php page instead of submitting

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to connect HTML form to SQL database using PHP but when I hit submit, it is giving me PHP page.

**This is HTML code**

```
<form method="post" action="connect.php">
    Username : <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
    Password : <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Here is PHP code**

```
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
    if (!empty($username)){
    if (!empty($password)){
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $dbname = "youtube";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()){
    die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno() .') '
    . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO account (username, password)
    values ('$username','$password')";
    if ($conn->query($sql)){
    echo "New record is inserted sucessfully";
    }
    else{
    echo "Error: ". $sql ."
    ". $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
    }
    }
    else{
    echo "Password should not be empty";
    die();
    }
    }
    else{
    echo "Username should not be empty";
    die();
    }
```

I expect to get 'New record is inserted successfully' or 'error'

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `php`, once you done with the various processes in a page, you need to write a redirect otherwise it will just die waiting for the next action. At the moment, after its done executing, you it will just `echo` if successful and `die()` is failed as per your conditions.

Add:

```
if ($conn->query($sql)){
   header("Location: /path_of_page.html");
}
```

The same can be applied in the `}else (){}` statements.

Edit: I forgot to mention, avoid using `die` and `echo` in intermediate (processing) pages since they will output on the raw php during executions. Rather, put them in an array and pass them to the UI as parameter.

Comment: Thanks Antony, but where can i add that?

Comment: The simplest way would be using `sessions`, that way you can define a `$_SESSION['errors']` , This is a global variable and is available in the scope of your application

Comment: You should also put die(); straight after the Location header... that's good practice so that the page doesn't accidentally continue executing and leak information that was supposed to be secure or wasn't intended for this context. While that wouldn't be visible in a browser, other clients such as a search engine, spam crawler or some malicious bot would be able to read it. It's a good habit to get into.